# How to tick any given check box inside a form?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, echo

```
for ($i=0; $i<$total_questions_for_exam; $i++) {


        $question_id= $question_and_answers[$i]['question_id'];
        $numberofanswersperquestion = count_answers_belongToOne_questionNew($question_id);
        //die(var_dump($question_id)); 
        $student_answer_per_question = retrieve_student_result ($_SESSION['user_id'], $_GET['quiz_id'], $question_id);
        $correct_answer = $numberofanswersperquestion[0]['answer_name'];

         echo ' <form method="post" id="review_form" name="review_form" action="view_user_summary.php">   
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-datatable table-hover review_marks">
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%"><strong>Question '. ($i+1) .'</strong></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%">' . $question_and_answers[$i]['question_name'] .'</td>
                    </tr>';

                    if($student_answer_per_question == '') 
                      echo  '<tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="warning"><em>Question Not attempted</em><br><strong>Correct Answer is </strong><br>' . $numberofanswersperquestion[0]['answer_name'] . '</td>
                            </tr>';

                    else if ($student_answer_per_question == $correct_answer)

                     echo  '<tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="success"><strong>Your answer is correct.</strong><br>' . $student_answer_per_question .'</td>
                            </tr>';

                    else 
                        echo    '<tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: left;" width="100%" class="danger">
                                        <table style="width: 100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="width: 50%"><strong>Your Answer</strong></th>
                                                    <th style="width: 50%"><strong>Correct Answer</strong></th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width: 50%">' . $student_answer_per_question . '</td>
                                                    <td style="width: 50%">' . $correct_answer .'</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>';

                    echo 

                    '<tr>
                        <td style="height: 5px;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="height: 5px;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="[ form-group ] correct_answer">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-primary"  id="fancy-checkbox-primary" autocomplete="off" />
                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="[ btn btn-primary ]">
                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                        <span> </span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                        Correct Answer
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>';

}

echo '<button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary submitbutton" type="submit" style="margin-top:100px;" name="submit_review">Submit Review</button></form>';
```

Hi guys this code above basically just pulls all the question and asnwers in my database. What I am trying to achieve is to have a check box within this for loop where it allows the users to tick the box to say that the answer is correct, or if they don't do anything assume the answer is wrong.

[Screenshot of how it looks](https://gyazo.com/b5d590e51a036944e61ab1fead2928cf)

It display as how I wanted it to be but one problem, when I click on the 2nd check box, the first one still ticking, I do not have control of the 2nd check box. Any idea how I can go about fixing this ?

Thought it would be a good idea to show a video of what I meant, I have provided a link to it.

[Problem](https://gyazo.com/6b0abd6a96f38a0eb944a8b416fbeff6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in a loop:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-primary" id="fancy-checkbox-primary" autocomplete="off" />
```

Which means your checkboxes all have the same `id`.  That's invalid markup, and the behavior of any code which attempts to use that `id` is going to be undefined.  (It might find the first matching element, the last matching element, all matching elements, no matching elements, etc.)

An `id`, as the name implies, is meant to *identify* an element.  You need to correct the markup so that elements can be properly identified, as well as adjust any code which uses those elements to identify them.

This could involve appending a value to the `id` in the loop, making each one unique.  Or perhaps using a `class` instead of an `id` for this.  From the code in the question I can't really speak to the latter, but the former should be simple enough:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-primary" id="fancy-checkbox-primary-' . $i . '" autocomplete="off" />
```

(Note: I'm not entirely familiar with the mechanism you're using to style these checkboxes, clearly there's some plugin at play here.  It's possible you may also need to similarly modify the `name` and/or `for` attributes associated with this `id` value as well.  Basically anything in the code, shown in the question or otherwise, which relies on the `id`.)

Though it's still not 100% clear what the implications of this would be to code *not* included in the question, so you may need to tinker for your own needs.  But fundamentally the issue here is the repeated `id` values.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, is there anyway we can take this into a chat room ? if that is fine with you ?

Comment: @jomin_george94: I'm not really here to have conversations, just to answer questions.  If there's some clarification to the question or additional information regarding the problem, that should be included in the question itself and not in a private session so that others with the same problem can also be helped.

Comment: It' just that I tried to append variable $i into the id and that doesn't seems to work at all, instead now it doesn't even check the box for the first one

Comment: @jomin_george94: I'm not familiar with the mechanism used by whatever plugin you're using, but the `name` and `for` attributes may also need to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks alot that fixed it, I did exactly what you told me, by appending the variable $i on to the id as well as modifying the for attribute to what ever I had for the id.